# Java Replace Regex not working

Tags: java, regex

Why doesn't this line of code work? It's supposed to replace all the punctuations with nothing.

```
m = m.replace("[\\?\\.;:'\"]", "")
```

m will not change after executing this line in java even though it contains punctuations. Why?

Comment: Dasblinkenlight nailed it.  As a side note, there's no need to escape a question mark or period inside a character class.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is because [`replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) takes a `String`; you need to call [`replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29), which does take a regular expression.